# Как изменять ImageView из другого класса?

Tags: java, android

Есть `MainActivity.java` с `activity_main.xml`. Есть `Test.java` с `test.xml`.

В `test.xml` есть `ImageView` `picture`. Как мне получить доступ к `picture` из `MainActivity.java`? Естественно, через `findViewByID` в `MainActivity.java` при попытке найти `ImageView picture`, который находится под классом `Test.java`, все скатывается в ошибку с `null`.

Пробовал объявлять в `Test.java` этой вьюшке `public static ImageView picture`, но студия ругается на возможную утечку памяти.

**Как мне получить доступ к этому `ImageView` из `MainActivity.java`?**

Comment: а вы как-то можете перейти на вашу активити `test` с `mainactivity`?

Comment: Ну, например через Drawer-меню. Я в вопросе как пример привел активити и классы, в реальности проект сложнее :)

Comment: вы я так понял хотите что-то поменять в своем `imageview` в `test` из `mainactivity`? картинку например или что-то типа такого?

Comment: Да, все верно!!

Comment: сейчас добавлю ответ, как бы я решал эту проблему)

Comment: Я пробовал через public void Update в дочернем классе и public ImageView getImageView() в родительском. Скатывается в null при попытке присвоить GONE для видимости ImageView. Т.е. саму вьюшку он находит, что уже радует, но не может ей свойства изменить.

Comment: Предполагаю, что можно через put\extra intent , но мне кажется должен быть способ более логичный))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом того что доступа из одного класса к виджетам или элементам другого нету в вашем случае, я бы вам посоветовал метод которым я пользуюсь у себя в проекте. Вероятнее всего у вас есть элемент интерфейса при помощи которого вы можете добавлять или менять картинку в `imageView` другого класса, кнопка например. Вот я бы вам посоветовал при нажатии на эту кнопку, или даже при создании активити `mainActivity` в функции `onCreate` сохранять в память устройства какую-то переменную. И дальше в вашей активити `test` при ее создании тяните ее, эту переменную. Если у вас например есть несколько картинок и вам из одной активити нужно ставить разные картинки на фон виджета, то сделайте условие которое будет проверять какая переменная находится в памяти и соответственно ставить уже картинку.

Как другой вариант можете передавать через `intent`. Но это слишком грубо для такой задачи, но как вариант можно его использовать, и будет работать. Либо есть еще третий вариант - очень сильно запарится и попытаться достать виджет другой активити. Но мне кажется что лучше так не рисковать, потому-что очень многое может пойти не так.

Надеюсь я помог в решении вашей проблемы, если будут вопросы или возникнут сложности, то не стесняйтесь и пишите. Помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: А это интересно... Public static int viewImage = 1, и дальше уже от нее плясать. Отличный вариант, спасибо!

Comment: не очень понимаю о чем вы говорите, как вы будете использовать ту строку которую вы упомянули?

Comment: Если в двух словах - есть свичер. Меняем по свичеру viewImage на 1 или 0. Если 1 - то вьюшка с картинкой показывается, если 0 = то GONE.

Comment: вы не так поняли ответ. @AndrewGoroshko говорил вам не про переменные, а про Preferences (а возможно и бд, если настроек куча).

Comment: Ну мой вариант уже сработал :D

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, я все пробовал понять о чем пишет автор)) думал может я что-то непонятно написал, уже думал ответ поменять

Comment: Да все отлично! Я просто не подумал про переменную :)

Comment: @АртемИльинский но вы подумайте над сохранением настроек, скорее всего пригодится в вашем проекте)))

Comment: Юзаю TinyDB. Есть куча кастомных массивов, и она работает :) Добавлю в сохранения еще и настройки :)